# Diagnosing freezing/hanging

Tags: 13.04, freeze

How can I diagnose random freezing on Ubuntu? I've tried fresh reinstalls several times but the OS still freezes often.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  That question is about how to recover from a hang; this question is about how to diagnose the cause of hangs.

Answer (score 1):

The freezing usually can occur due to HDD failing or/and a problem with graphics card driver.

- So first check the HDD for bad sectors. Open the **Disks** utility and check the S.M.A.R.T and see if disk is Healthy.

[image]

- Then you can install an additional driver for your graphics card (if any). This can be done from Ubuntu Software Center → Edit → Software Sources and activate a binary-proprietary driver. 
  Reboot your system for changes to take effect. 
  An example for Nvidia

[image]

- Also you can run a memtest from grub menu (memtest86+). Leave it for 30-40 minutes at least an see if any weird - red lines - messages appears.

If the problem persists, you can check some logs for weird - error messages

```
cat var/log/Xorg.0.log 
dmesg
```

Comment: My disks utility looks different than yours and I don't see any "S.M.A.R.T." area that I can check.

http://imgur.com/utUX5Qp

I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed. How do I run the memtest?

Comment: Click the gears and you will see S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: OK, there are three types of tests "Short", "Extended", and "Conveyance". What should I choose?

Comment: No necessary to run tests. Check the attributes, are all OK ?

Comment: Yes, both hard drives say "OK" under Assessment.

Comment: Note that memtest86 is no longer available under Ubuntu (I can't find a way to get it in my grub menu on 16.04, and it's not even available on my 14.04 install DVD), so that part of this answer is obsolete.